# export sharepoint modifications to a separate table

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint file that many users can modify.

I can view historic changes by

[image]

and

[image]

Is it possible to export this complete history to a separate table from the beginning of time, showing the old and updated value, as well as when it was done and who performed the action? I have not been able to find a way, and might be missing someting

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to export completed history to a separate table from the beginning of time.

Comment: Thanks @Emily Du. is it possible to export the current data from present time onwards?