# inspect elements of sharepoint file to scrape

Tags: html, web-scraping, sharepoint, tags

As a follow up from [export sharepoint modifications to a separate table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75791708/export-sharepoint-modifications-to-a-separate-table)

I would like to scrape data from an excel sharepoint file, but when I inspect the elements, I cannot find the tags associated with the changes. I can only find the tag asscociated with the entire page. Does anyone know how to identify the tags for the `changes`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use element inspecter tool on top left of DevTools
   [DevTools element inspecter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJGhD.png)

I tried with my file and found that it was in this tag

> ```
> <div class="ms-List" aria-label="list of changes card" role="listbox"></div>
> ```

[List of changes snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdWp7.png)